Model predict in keras strange output
Wrong results getting the classified classes of a neural network with high accuracy.
Hi guys,
I am moving my first steps in keras, and I am not able to understand if the output of a function is correct or not. Here the problem.
I am using pandas and keras to load and elaborate a dataset. I create a simple depth neural network to analyze a dataset quite famous online: the Breast Cancer Wisconsin. After loaded the dataset and create train and test sets, I train and evaluate the model:
model = Sequential() # Empty model
model.add( Dense(12, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="relu"))
model.add( Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")) 

model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit( X_train, Y_train, epochs=100)

print( "\nEvaluation: ", model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test) )

The output of the evaluation seems great and the results are here:
Evaluation:  [0.08850488066673279, 0.9766082167625427]

That should be quite 100% of accuracy. Then I want to retrieve the classification output of the model in order to build a confusion matrix. For this reason I tried to use the predict function of keras, but I obtain only 0 as predicted class. Attaching the code here:
print("Test set: ", Y_test)
y_prediction = model.predict(X_test)
y_prediction = np.argmax (y_prediction, axis = 1)
print("Prediction set:", y_prediction)

As you can see in the previous code, firstly I print out the correct value of the classification, than I run the predict function, tying to associate to each calculated value the corresponding class (0 or 1).
This is the output
Test set:  [0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 646us/step
Prediction set: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

My question is: am I wrong trying to get in this way the output classes? How is possible that the accuracy is very high if the results are like this?
Thanks,
----- EDIT -----
It was a mistake in the elaboration of the elaboration of the prediction vector. Instead of using the argmax  function, I moved to a threshold value:
y_prediction = y_prediction > 0.5
y_prediction = y_prediction.astype(int)


argmax is not correct if you only have one neuron, for that you threshold > 0.5

Thanks for the reply @Dr.Snoopy. However, I checked the output of the predict function and seems that all the values are close to 0.0 (or like 0.0). In fact if i print the y_predict array, I have values like this: [9.99840379e-01]  [9.09719430e-03]
[4.00111526e-02]...  So also the threshold will give me 0 as class.

9.998e-1 is 0.998, not close to zero. The issue is still the same.

Oh! Of course you are right! Thanks a lot, I was so confused by the notation. I will edit the question with your suggestions. Thanks
